# App kept stop running in Emulator in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I've been following a tutorial on YouTube about tab layouts and when I was finish following it and run the application, the app kept stop running. So, I open my logcat to see what was wrong and it says: "Caused by java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager cannot be cast to com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout". I was unable to find what "cannot be cast to" means and can't find any documents explaining it.

```
private Toolbar toolbar;
private ViewPager viewPager;
private TabLayout tabLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbarClipBridge);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewpagerClipBridge);
    tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.viewpagerClipBridge);

    fragmentDevices fragmentDevices = new fragmentDevices();
    fragmentSyncActivity fragmentSyncActivity = new fragmentSyncActivity();
    fragmentSettings fragmentSettings = new fragmentSettings();

    ViewPageAdapter viewPageAdapter = new ViewPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), 0);
    viewPageAdapter.addFragment(fragmentDevices, "Devices");
    viewPageAdapter.addFragment(fragmentSyncActivity, "Sync Activity");
    viewPageAdapter.addFragment(fragmentSettings, "Settings");
    viewPager.setAdapter(viewPageAdapter);

    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_devices_24);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_sync_24);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_settings_24);

}

private class ViewPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private List<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<String> fragmentTitle = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPageAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm, int behavior) {
        super(fm, behavior);
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title){
        fragments.add(fragment);
        fragmentTitle.add(title);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragments.size();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return fragmentTitle.get(position);
    }
}
```

Logcat:

Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager cannot be cast to com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout

[Image of my logcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vog6f.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line:

```java
viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewpagerClipBridge);
tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.viewpagerClipBridge);
```

The code tries to look into your `activity_main.xml` file and find an XML object with the id `R.id.viewpagerClipBridge`. The XML object is probably of the type ViewPager.

In the following line, the code looks again into the XML file. Again, with the id `R.id.viewpagerClipBridge`, the code tries to set the return value to a variable `tab layout` of type `TabLayout`.

And since the type of ViewPager != type of TabLayout it cannot be cast to that type.

I think you used the wrong id in the second `findViewById` line. Investigate your `activity_main.xml` and look for the id of your `TabLayout`.

Comment: No wonder they say to not copy and paste your own code. Thanks!